Desplegar website creado con Nextjs 14 en donweb
Tengo una landing page creada con nextjs14 y no estoy encontrando la manera de desplegarla en donweb. Esta es mi primera vez que quiero hacer esto y los tutoriales recomiendan hacerlo con vercel. El asunto es que el cliente ya tiene contratado donweb con dominio incluido.
Alguien se topo con esta situacion?
Desde ya muchas gracias

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Pero cual seria el problema??? no te dicen ellos como hacer el despligue??? que esperas que te contesten aca si no pones cual es la dificultad?
